# Elements not fitting correctly properly with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a little search menu with plain html and CSS. I am working with percentages to fit my elements together however they seem to overlap, when in my mind I would have thought they'd fit together nicely. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style media="screen">
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 5px
      }
      .search-menu {
        height: 600px;
        background: #00003b;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px
      }
      .search-menu-list {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-menu-list input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
      }
      .search-menu-list ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        background: white;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .search-menu-list li {
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
        margin: -1px -1px 0 -1px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        cursor: default;
      }
      .search-menu-list li:hover {
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="search-menu">
      <div class="search-menu-list">
        <input placeholder="Start typing to search...">
        <ul>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
        </ul>
      <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main culprit here is the `padding` on the `.search-menu-list input`:

```css
.search-menu-list input {
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
```

This can be better made this way, by wrapping it with another `<div class="input-wrap">` and give the following style:

```css
.search-menu-list .input-wrap {
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}

.search-menu-list .input-wrap input {
  padding: 0;
}
```

For the `height` not working right, you already use fixed height (`600px`) for the container, and you are giving `height: 100%` to the list. So give:

```css
.search-menu-list {
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In future, adding this works:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

This is mainly because of adding `width: 100%`, `border` and `padding` together.

And you have `<div>`, which should be `</div>`, just before last `</div>`.

It is because of the box model. Check the output of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style media="screen">
      * {box-sizing: border-box;}
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 5px
      }
      .search-menu {
        height: 600px;
        background: #00003b;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px
      }
      .search-menu-list {
        height: 550px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-menu-list input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
      }
      .search-menu-list ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        background: white;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .search-menu-list li {
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
        margin: -1px -1px 0 -1px;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        cursor: default;
      }
      .search-menu-list li:hover {
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="search-menu">
      <div class="search-menu-list">
        <input placeholder="Start typing to search...">
        <ul>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
          <li>This is a test list item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/wimeqazusi**

Comment: Agree for the padding, not agree for the margin. The total box size is `width + padding + border`, margins doesn't affect to the total with of a box.

Comment: Just adding `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` is very bad practice on an existing project, it can easily break the rest of the layout

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Updated.

Comment: @dcohenb Yes, I understand.

Comment: @PraveenKumar looks more reasonable

Comment: @dcohenb Thank you so much for correcting my mistake. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar What about the list box overlapping on the bottom?

Comment: @JacobMason Looking on it.

Comment: @JacobMason You have to reduce the textbox height from the `<div>`.

Comment: @JacobMason `height: 550px;` for the `.search-menu-list`. See [**Fiddle**](http://output.jsbin.com/wimeqazusi).

Comment: @JacobMason Updated in the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I want to be able to change the height of the .search-menu and have the list re-size. Hence why I was using percentages. Is there no way around this?

Comment: @JacobMason FlexBox FTW. Have a look at that too?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok! Don't worry, I've upvoted because is the correct and the good answer (and explained very fine)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank you so much for the help buddy. `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```css
.search-menu-list input{
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px;  /*Remove padding */
  padding:0;
}
```